# Why doesn't the javasript run on this commandlink

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why the javascript doesn't show the alert? FYI, I took out alot of the apex code so it's easier to read. All I need is to know why the Alert doesn't pop up and warn the user when they click on a link.

Thanks

```
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageblock >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" id="pbsCon" >
                <apex:outputPanel id="panelCon">
                    <div id="loading-curtain-div"/>

                    <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbtCon" value="{!listGoalsCurrYear}" var="cpgs">
                        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="cnt"/>   
                        <apex:column headervalue="Action">
                            <apex:commandlink value="Remove" onclick="return validateFunction();" action="{!removeRecord}" immediate="true">
                <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount</apex:facet>                                                         
                            <apex:inputField id="ga" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Goal Amount Comments</apex:facet>                            
                            <apex:inputField id="gac" value="{!cpgs.Goal_Amount_Comments__c}" rendered="True" />
                        </apex:column>   

                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>


                    </apex:pageBlockTable>

                </apex:outputPanel>                
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
    <script>    
    <!– Java script starts Here –>
        function validateFunction(){

        alert('Are you sure you want to remove this row?');
    }
    <!– java script ends here –>
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: can you remove "return" from onclick attribute and try?

Comment: I remove it but no pop-up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commenting in the script block is not valid. Change to this:

```
<script>    
    //Java script starts Here
        function validateFunction(){

        alert('Are you sure you want to remove this row?');
    }
    //java script ends here
    </script>
```

The `<!-- -->` is valid in visualforce markup, use /** */ in javascript although as per sfdcfox comment you should be able to use the VF comment in JS if you ensure you use the double dashes.

Comment: When it removed the comments it worked. I changed it to confirm(). How to get it that when the user clicks cancel it does nothing but if they click ok it continues to remove the action?

Comment: Use regular html button then if they click ok call an actionfunction. I do not believe that returning false in the onclick of the command button will stop the server call but you could try that as well

Comment: `<!-- -->` would have worked... But note the double dashes. These comments are allowed in script blocks.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Nice catch. did not notice that, but I do know I have had issues using <!-- --> in JS before but it could have been unrelated. I ensure I use /** */ in JS just to make sure. Updated answer to reflect your comments though. Thanks

Comment: @Eric you're welcome. I just wouldn't want people to get the wrong impression. I do admit, though, using html comments in a script block feels... Wrong. Sadly, that's only allowed because of backwards compatibility with browsers nobody even remembers.